# Delayed_job not saving in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, delayed-job

I am using Ruby on Rails and trying to add a feature for scheduling notification push by using delayed job. I implemented the gem as per documentation and started workers by running `rake jobs:work` but despite my best efforts, no job is being saved. I tried `Delayed::Job.all` in the console but it returns an empty array no matter what I do.

my model:

```
class MessageSocialAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :social_account_id, :message_id, :read_time, :push_notification
  attr_reader :when_to_run
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :social_account

  def when_to_run
    message.deliver_at || Time.now
  end

  def push
    social_account.send_push(msg_sca.message)
    update_attributes!(:push_notification => true)
  end
  handle_asynchronously :push, :run_at => Proc.new {|i| i.when_to_run }
end
```

I can see no delayed_job.log in the logs and development.log does not contain any clues.

Would you have any ideas what the problem might be? Thanks

*EDIT
the model that I am calling it from:
message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  def send_push_to_all(delivery_time=nil)
    self.message_social_accounts.map{|msg_sca| msg_sca.push} unless self.reward.status=="qa"
    self.update_attributes!(:sent_at => Time.now)
  end
end
```

The call comes from the controller:

```
msg.send_push_to_all(msg.deliver_at)
```

Comment: What happens when you call `bin/delayed_job` ?

Comment: Where are you calling the push method?

Comment: Magnuss I get ``` ERROR: no command given```
```Usage: delayed_job <command> <options> -- <application options>```

Comment: NickM =>  ```handle_asynchronously :push, :run_at => Proc.new {|i| i.when_to_run }``` and the push method is directly above it.

Comment: did you start delayed job ? output of `script/delayed_job status` ?

Comment: Nithin the output is ```script/delayed_job: No such file or directory``. Is this script supposed to be automatically generated when I run ```rails generate delayed_job:active_record``` or is it something that has to be added manually? By the way I am currently working locally.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but are you calling push in an after_save callback or something? You still have to call the push method for it to be handled asynchronously.

Comment: NickM yes, sorry of course, I am calling it in another model: ```message_social_accounts.map{|msg_sca| msg_sca.push} unless reward.status=="qa"```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the app I was working on had already implemented Sidekiq for another purpose and looks like those 2 interfered. When the Sidekiq interface was opened I could see the jobs in there eventhough they were not showing in the delayed job queries.